# How to make an arch oval at the edges

Tags: edges

this is my first time on blender so please bear with me. After 6 hours of trying deformers, scaling, all the tutorials I could get my hand into I got no solution… I am lost in this and about to quit using blender, it's frustrating to try what seems to be a simple thing and get nowhere.

[image: Headphone Cushions]

If someone could do a quick fix in it and show me how it's done would be great.

Thank you to all
Ilda

[Blender .zip file](https://workupload.com/file/ULw5M6KZFQm)

Comment: You shared your reference image, but what exactly is the arch oval - do you want to create a "U" shaped curve? What have you tried, perhaps a Bezier curve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but if you adjust your background image a little it almost perfectly lines up with a circle.  Here I have a cylinder with 16 segments and it matches the shape of the headphones:

[image]

I don't know what tutorials you're using but I would suggest a few things to make it easier:

- cut the headphones in half and use a mirror modifier.  Then you only need to model half of it. If you want asymmetry you can add it later!
- if you're using a subdivision modifier anyway, try to use as few vertices/edges as possible. The more you have the harder it is to make changes.
- if you really want to continue with what you have, I would create a set of circle meshes and snap the vertices to them. Here I created 3 'circle' meshes with 64 vertices and lined them up with the headphones.  You could snap your vertices to those edges - but that's a fair amount of work.

[image]

Hope this is helpful, or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: *If you want asymmetry you can add it later* - that's a great tip especially for an object that is symmetrical by design but then small asymmetry kicks in due to imperfections in production or the way the object physically rests when taking a photo etc.